Validate Additional Info Using Pydantic Model
I'm a new user of FastAPI. I'm writing a small web application and I'm wondering if it's good practice to validate additional information, which is not directly related to the object itself, using the Pydantic model itself? For example, checking if a user with such a name exists in the database.
For example:
class CreateUser(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(strict=True)
    username: str = Field(pattern=r"[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%&*_.-]{3,}")
    password: str
    secret: str
    
    @field_validator("username")
    def validate_username(cls, value: str):
        # check if user is exist in DB...
        # if no, return the username
        # if yes, raise error


FastAPI may have some suggestions on what best practice is. In my experience, keeping the models fairly self contained leads to longer code, possibly more complicated code, but in the end easier to maintain code. YMMV.

Take a look at SQLModel which is from the same author as FastAPI

A model should only validate for a valid request (this also tangles up the error handling, since you won't reach the body of the function if the validation fails). Second, you probably want to make use of the dependency injection in FastAPI for the database session handling.

pydantic model is only here to validate the request and respone schema and type hints, nothing else. for you to keep username unique  you need to add constraint in the db model username field ,that the unique=True that is all you need to do

In my opinion you shouldn't do that.
In FastAPI, to me, Pydantic acts as a gateway to the path operation function(whether it is input or output). It deserializes, cleans(and/or converts) and validates the data so that you can count on that the data you receive is in the good shape. The rest is going to be passed to the path operation function or service layer if you have. I'll decouple the job of checking the availability of the user in database from Pydantic models.
